# Javascript promise never resolves

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am using [rotateByDegrees](https://nathan.kellenicki.com/node-poweredup/devices_tachomotor.js.html#sunlight-1-line-146) from a library called node-poweredup in a typescript project:

```
motor.rotateByDegrees(20,10).then(function(value) {console.log("test");}, function(value) {console.log("error");});
```

I would expect to see "test" after successful completion, but the promise never resolves. If I use await, it hangs on the await line forever.
Replicating the syntax that appears to be used in the rotateByDegrees function:

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve) => { return resolve(); });
```

does not compile, I get `error TS2794: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0. Did you forget to include 'void' in your type argument to 'Promise'?` I can make it compile and behave as expected with `resolve(true)`, but how does it compile in the library then? Do I misunderstand promises? Some feature in typescript? A bug in the library? I am a newbie to JavaScript, I don't want to over-complicate this question by including irrelevant details. If you can give me hints on what I am missing and how to debug this, I can provide all relevant details.

Comment: Maybe the library is not written in TypeScript at all? Or they ignore the error? Or they actually *do* return a `Promise<void>`?

Comment: You're asking a lot of questions and they seem to be the wrong ones. Your code is *fine* but not for the TS compiler with your settings. You can go around it by supplying a type argument `new Promise<void>()`. Whatever the library did would compile maybe because they don't try to resolve an empty promise or because they use different TS compiler settings...or it's not written in TS at all. You'd consume it as a dependency, so your TS settings won't apply. None of that really helps you with your issue, however.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers, TS and compiler settings is what I also suspected. I used the same function in a *.js file before and executed it with node, there it does resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the helpful comments I was able to narrow it down to the compilation of the library. I did in fact not use a pre-compiled binary but had to compile the library myself using electron-rebuild to make the bluetooth adapter work. I did the following test:

```
git clone https://github.com/nathankellenicki/node-poweredup.git
cd node-poweredup
npm install
npm run build
```

this compiles without error. I created the following test file

```
const PoweredUP = require("node-poweredup");

const poweredUP = new PoweredUP.PoweredUP();
poweredUP.scan(); // Start scanning for hubs

console.log("Looking for Hubs...");

poweredUP.on("discover", async (hub) => { // Wait to discover hubs

    await hub.connect(); // Connect to hub
    console.log(`Connected to ${hub.name}!`);

    const motorA = await hub.waitForDeviceAtPort("A"); // Make sure a motor is plugged into port A
    motorA.rotateByDegrees(20,10).then(function(value) {console.log("test");});

});
```

and get the expected output:

```
node-poweredup$ node test.js 
Looking for Hubs...
Connected to MyHub2!
test
Connected to MyHub3!
test
```

When I changed the first line to

```
const PoweredUP = require(".");
```

to make it use my self-compiled binary I get

```
node-poweredup$ node test.js 
Looking for Hubs...
Connected to MyHub2!
Connected to MyHub3!
```

Of course this is only a partial answer because I still don't know why it compiles differently on my machine, but at least I have an idea where to start searching for the problem.